# Can we pair off [pairing] with [bluetooth]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[pairing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pairing) is a tag specifically for pairing bluetooth devices, according to it's Wiki. However I'm not convinced it's different enough of a topic area from [bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) to warrant it's own tag.

Should we Synonymise [pairing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pairing) -> [bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth)?

Comment: Bah! Yes, let's go through the 17 questions, remove the tag and then forget it ever existed.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I got into a zone and suggested all the edits. Once they're cleared we can [status-complete]. (One day I will reach 2k on SU, and it will be glorious lol)